# How to check when the react components get rendered or rerendered

Tags: reactjs, react-redux

Is there any way to get logs of which all React components get rendered or rerendered when any event/action is performed. I just want to check whether any unwanted React component is getting rerendered. I know we could achieve this by adding consoles in render function, componentWillReceiveProps or componentWillUpdate. But I have number of components in my webapp. Adding console statements in each component would be a mess. Is there a better way?

Comment: you can put a alert code in render method to do this

Comment: https://github.com/facebook/react-devtools might help with tracing updates

Answer (score 20, accepted):

A nice option is to visualise React components in the chrome timeline. This lets you see which components exactly get mounted, updated, and unmounted and how much time they take relative to each other. That feature was added as part of the release of React 15.4.0. You can take a look at the [official blogpost](https://facebook.github.io/react/blog/2016/11/16/react-v15.4.0.html) to get a better insight, but summing up, those are the steps to get it up and running:

1. Load your app with ?react_perf in the query string (for example, http://localhost:3000/?react_perf).
2. Open the Chrome DevTools Timeline tab and press Record.
3. Perform the actions you want to profile. Don't record more than 20 seconds or Chrome might hang.
4. Stop recording.
5. React events will be grouped under the User Timing label.

After that, you will get a cool visual representation of mounting, updating and unmounting of your different components over time

Comment: Where can I find this 'User Timing' label?

Comment: Great guide! Update: `Chrome DevTools Timeline` is now called `Chrome DevTools Performance`

Answer (score 6):

In addition to rauliyohmc answer. Profiling tool he described is really helpful and powerful, but if your task is just checking if there are unnecessary re-renders (i.e. ones which did not lead to DOM changes) you can use nice and simple  [react-addons-perf](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/perf.html) tool. It has `printWasted` method which will provide you info about wasted re-renders.

Comment: react-addons-perf isn't supported anymore in React v16+